# flutter firebase cannot upload image "[firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action."

Tags: flutter, firebase

current firebase storage security rules:

```
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profile_images/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null
                   && request.auth.uid == userId
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                   && request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024; // Limit image size to 10MB
    }
  }
```

Flutter code:

```
class ProfileService {
  static final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  static final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  static Future updateProfilePicture() async {
    final user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user == null) return;
    print("User ID: ${user.uid}");
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    try {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        final imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
        final storageRef = _storage.ref().child('profile_images/${user.uid}.png');
        print(storageRef.fullPath);
        await storageRef.putFile(imageFile);
        final imageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

        await user.updatePhotoURL(imageUrl);
        EventStream.putEvent(Event(EventType.PROFILE_PICTURE_UPDATED));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("ERROR: $error");
    }
  }
}
```

The plan is pretty simple. A user should upload an image to firebase storage and update his/her `user.imageURL`. User is signed in and I have tried it with multiple user. One important thing is when I remove `request.auth.id == userId` the images are getting uploaded.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the problem is in "profile_images/${user.uid}.png". this should be "profile_images/${user.uid}/image_name.png". because security rule is /profile_images/{userId}/{allPaths=**}.

Comment: Just Update final storageRef = _storage.ref().child('profile_images/${user.uid}.png'); to final storageRef = _storage.ref().child('profile_images/${user.uid}/profile.png');. let me know if it works.

Comment: if it work - update path - "profile_images/${user.uid}/images/image_name.png" because I think image path should be in even segment.

Comment: @RajendraAVerma Good catch!  Wanna post that as an answer?

Comment: And: Cloud Storage for Firebase doesn't care about the odd/even number of segment, only Firestore does. :)

Comment: ok yes that worked. If you want you can post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct answer. Also if I want profile_images/userId.png, how should I modify the security rules? And thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with Storage Path

to align with the security rule `/profile_images/{userId}/{allPaths=**}`, we need to adjust this path to: `profile_images/${user.uid}/image_name.png`.

Before :

```
final storageRef = _storage.ref().child('profile_images/${user.uid}.png');
```

After :

```
final storageRef =_storage.ref().child('profile_images/${user.uid}/profile.png');
```

This simple change will resolve the issue and ensure the correct path is used for our storage operations.

**OR**

If you want `profile_images/userId.png` as storage path then you have to modify the security rules as

```
match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /profile_images/{imageId} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if request.auth != null
                 && imageId == '${request.auth.uid}.png'
                 && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
                 && request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024; // Limit image size to 10MB
  }
}
```